# Performance Counter and Disk properties show different values

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server, performance-monitor

I am looking at free disk space in windows server,i have D: drive of 499 GB, when looking at performance monitor counters, free megabytes in logical disk counter shows free MB as 486,066 MB which is 486 GB free space, when i look from disk properties it shows there is 474 GB of free space which one is accurate.

Comment: 1GB = 1024 MB.  486,066 / 1024 = 474 GB

Comment: So both are accurate.

Comment: Gigabytes can differ up to 7% (1 Gib =  1073741824 bytes, 1 Gb = 1000000000 bytes).